# Retain co-ordinates of iframe / div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Developing dashboard (has images) having zoom option. I've two iframe for showing content one by one to avoid flickring. Now I'm facing challenge to implement google pan view kind of functionality so that if I zoom on first frame and goes to some (x,y) co-ordinate. After refresh second iframe should be aligned to that position only.

Comment: That is a challenge alright - have you had any thoughts how you could do it?

Comment: @Jaromanda Challenge for me.. looking for suggestion. One solution which I'm looking for is to have divs instead of iframe to show the content.

Comment: The issue with the question is that it is unclear what you are asking help for. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I've modified the question to clear the unclear part too :-). Yes I've tried to set the x,y co-ordinates of iframe to show the exact location something like    `var iframeX = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe_id').offsetLeft;
       // Get Top Position
       var iframeY = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe_id').offsetTop;`

Comment: maybe the `HTMLElement#getBoundingClientRect` will be useful

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this to get the last location now at the time of load I added this but inside div showing at (0,0) position `$('#insideDiv').css({ // 'zoom': 6, 'top':-341.949981689453, 'left':-223.87998962402344, 'right':2674.119873046875, 'bottom':534.0499877929687 });`